# Tabs now working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This piece of code is for some tabs, and is currently working fine, but I want to display the link on the 'webBar', so this way people can navigate to a page and see an specific tab

Example of what im trying to do is
Index.html#contenet3

```
$(function () {
    $(".tab-content").hide().first().show();
    $(".inner-nav li:first").addClass("active");

    $(".inner-nav a").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('li').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        $($(this).attr('href')).show().siblings('.tab-content').hide();
    });

    var hash = $.trim( window.location.hash );

    if (hash) $('.inner-nav a[href$="'+hash+'"]').trigger('click');

});
```

Comment: If they are "now working" and "currently working fine" then why ask a question? And what is a "webBar"? Do you mean the url as shown in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    var hash = $.trim(window.location.hash);
    var tab;
    console.log ("hash: " + hash);
    switch (hash) {
        case "#tab1":
            tab = 0;
            break;
        case "#tab2":
            tab = 1;
            break;
        case "#tab3":
            tab = 2;
            break;
        default:
            tab = 10;

    }
    console.log(tab);
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", tab);
```

You have to use the 'active' option and enter the index of the tab you want to show. If you want to use strings on your url then add the switch.